# get a specific field from mongo db with javascript, discord.js

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I made a blacklist command to blacklist users from my bot. I wanted it to message the user the reason why they were blacklisted but I can't figure out how to do that.

```js
        let profile = await Blacklist.findOne({
            userID: message.author.id,
        });
        let reasons = await Blacklist.findOne({
            userID: profile,
            reason: reasons
        })
        if (profile) return message.reply(`ur banned from using this bot lmao, reason: ${reasons}`)
```

however this outputs an error of

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'reasons' before initialization
```

this is what i have in mongoDB
[image: this is what i have in mongoDB]

Comment: `reason: reasons` where does *that* `reasons` come from?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're fetching the same document from MongoDB in both of your `findOne()` calls, because of how you simply use the profile that you just fetched in the first call to fetch a document in the second call. Shouldn't this work?

```js
let profile = await Blacklist.findOne({
    userID: message.author.id,
});
if (profile) return message.reply(`you're banned for reason: ${profile.reasons}`)
```

And the reason you're getting that `Cannot access 'reasons' before initialization` error is because in the second findOne call you set a new variable `reasons` to the return value of the function, but you pass the `reasons` variable into the expression on the right side, which is still executing, so your left side `reasons` variable has not been initialized. But that statement didn't make sense anyway; you should be able to just delete it.